# SKNavigationListener: The advices only change if a map is present

Tags: android, skmaps

In order to get the advices of a started navigation I have a singleton which implements the interface SKNavigationListener. If the activity (or fragment) is showing a navigation, the navigation state changes but if I change to another activity or fragment without a map, I still receive callbacks of this method:

```
onUpdateNavigationState(SKNavigationState navigationState)
```

But the received navigationState is always the same.

How can I get updated navigation states without showing a map?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Can you recreate this situation in the demo project?

Comment: I recreate the situation and it works like a charm! it was my fault, I did not continued calling`SKPositionerManager.getInstance().reportNewGPSPosition(currentPosition);` so I didn't received new advices. Sorry for wasting your time! Thanks a lot @Ando !

Comment: Great to hear that it works! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I did not continued calling `SKPositionerManager.getInstance().reportNewGPSPosition(currentPosition);‌​` so I didn't received new advices.